# How to change Intellij memory parameters set during installation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory, settings

I have the latest IntelliJ installed (2021.2.3) on Windows 10 with 64GB RAM (32 free) and a Threadripper 1950X CPU. I was running code inspection when IntelliJ crashed with `insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment`. The JetBrains website is vague about how it sets memory, saying only that:

> [The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) running IntelliJ IDEA allocates some predefined amount of memory. The default value depends on the platform.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html)

As @Basil Bourque pointed out, the max heap size setting can be accessed from `Help | Change Memory Settings`, which I did. What other settings are changeable and where are they?

Comment: What is vague about the directions to choose Help | Change Memory Settings? Your linked page shows a screenshot of the dialog box, with text selected where you enter your desired memory setting.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for your comment - I clarified my questions.

Comment: Other VM options can be found at Help | Edit Custom VM Options. You don't need to change anything unless instructed to do so by support or if you know what you are doing.